# Are the borromean rings a torus link?

Tags: knot-theory

The $(3,3)$ torus link produces three unknots that are pairwise linked, which makes me suspect that the borromean rings ─ which are otherwise rather similar ─ cannot be produced through any $(p,q)$ torus link combination, and therefore that there is no deformation of the borromean rings that will make them lie on a torus. However, my knot theory isn't strong enough to make a harder case for this, and there's no mention of any connections in either wikipedia page.

So: can the borromean links be deformed so that they will lay on the surface of a torus? If so, how? If not, why not?

Comment: Any non-trivial torus link with multiple components will have non-trivial pairwise linking number (in fact the same linking number with each component). This is not hard to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Borromean rings are not a torus link, which is what we call links that can lie on a torus.  To quote the [wikipedia article on the Borromean rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borromean_rings#Hyperbolic_geometry):

> The Borromean rings are a hyperbolic link: the complement of the Borromean rings in the 3-sphere admits a complete hyperbolic metric of finite volume.

Then we use the fact that every knot or link falls into one of three categories, this time using the [wikipedia article on Hyperbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_link):

> As a consequence of the work of William Thurston, it is known that every knot is precisely one of the following: hyperbolic, a torus knot, or a satellite knot. As a consequence, hyperbolic knots can be considered plentiful. A similar heuristic applies to hyperbolic links.

So, since the Borromean rings are hyperbolic, they cannot be a torus link. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably plenty. On the other hand - is there a more intuitive way to understand a hyperbolic link? or of why, say, the complement of the $(3,3)$ torus knot does not admit such a hyperbolic metric?

Comment: You could probably use the standard braid presentation for the borromean rings and show that it cannot be the braid word for a torus link.